# Tensorflow iNaturalist model detection_classes mean what?

Tags: tensorflow

I try [Tensorflow iNaturalist Species-trained models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md#inaturalist-species-trained-models)

faster_rcnn_resnet101_fgvc model,this model give me result:

```
{'detection_classes': [[2135.0, 1752.0, 360.0, 1160.0, 2553.0]], 'num_detections': [5.0], 'detection_scores': [[0.994473159, 0.354584545, 0.144689247, 0.0592163019, 0.0416594595]], 'detection_boxes': [[[0.0930139199, 0.150347397, 0.999965131, 0.826069772], [0.0657478347, 0.0819986314, 1.0, 0.880409956], [0.0652499944, 0.0473736562, 0.994987428, 0.905939639], [0.0780970305, 0.132595479, 1.0, 0.821907163], [0.0904432163, 0.14043197, 1.0, 0.848255813]]]}
```

I don't know `'detection_classes': [[2135.0, 1752.0, 360.0, 1160.0, 2553.0]]` mean what,I find [iNaturalist GBIF Info Excel](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JHn6J_9HBYyN5kaVrH1qcc3VMyxOsV2II8BvSwufM54/edit#gid=0)

,but don't match ,first pic 
[image] 's ID is not in detection_classes.So How to convert result to species name.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I find  [Tensorflow object_detection fgvc classes_label_map](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/data/fgvc_2854_classes_label_map.pbtxt),ID:2135 Marmota flaviventris is right.